# Java Regular Expression to match 1 to 5 asterisks only

Tags: java, regex

I have a text field where the user can enter a star rating for an organisation into a database where the column has a maximum length of 5.

I have tried using `".*\\*{1,5}$"` to match the string, but it doesn't seem to be working when I enter 6 characters.

The error message thrown from the database is:

[image]

I want to catch the input before that error message is triggered.

Comment: show your initial String and the expected result

Comment: Please provide sample strings. The regex is `[*]{1,5}`, but it might need adjustment.

Comment: `^\\*{1,5}$` this should do it for you

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" how? does it match strings it is not supposed to match? Does it fail to match strings it's supposed to match? Show the results you expected and the bad results that you got instead. Also, which matching method are you using? `matches`? `find`? Show the code.

Comment: Um, that error message bears no relation whatsoever to the question you asked, unless it happens that you're storing these asterisks in a column that has a maximum width of (say) 5.

Comment: That is the error message coming from the database I'm trying to insert the string into. That column is limited to 5 characters, but I want a regex to check the string before it goes in to the database so the user doesn't have to see that one.

Comment: Why is this getting down voted if it was a legitimate question, not already asked on SO, and I spent time looking at multiple other sites and questions trying to figure it out beforehand? Geez.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have tried using `".*\\*{1,5}$"`

That says "match any number of any character (possibly excluding newlines, depending on what flags you use) followed by 1-5 asterisks, at the end of the string," not "Match 1-5 asterisks." When you tested it with six asterisks, it passed the string because it matched the first five asterisks with the `.*` (because it's greedy) and then one asterisk at the end with the `\*{1,5}`.

To match just 1-5 asterisks and nothing else: `^\*{1,5}$` (as a string literal: `"^\\*{1,5}$"`). The `^` is the "beginning of input" anchor, `\*` (`\\*` in the string literal) is an escaped asterisk (since otherwise it has special meaning), `{1,5}` means "at least one and up to five times," and `$` is the "end of input" anchor. More in [the documentation for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Oh, by 'greedy' you mean it went back and continued matching until there were no more characters?

Comment: @JaidynBelbin: In regular expressions, something is "greedy" if it takes as much as it can from the input. It doesn't "go back," but if you look at `******` and the next thing in the regex to match is `.*`, since `*` is a greedy quantifier, it will take as many as it can. It can only take five, though, because if it took all six the `\*{1,5}` wouldn't have anything anymore.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the explanation